# Mysql how to group by using like operator using the split

Tags: mysql, sql

In mysql how to group by using like operator using the split

Let me try to clear the things.

Suppose we have these product keys

```
| 42131607-0001-01 | (id:1)
| 42131607-0001-02 | (id:2)
| 42131607-0002-01 | (id:3)
| 42131607-0002-01 | (id:4)
| 42131607-0002-02 | (id:5)
| 42131607-0002-02 | (id:6)
| 42131607-0003-01 | (id:7)
| 42131607-0003-01 | (id:8)
| 42131607-0004-05 | (id:9)
```

Now we have to find unique products on the basis of these keys . So in this our unique products are

```
| 42131607-0001-01 | (id:1)
| 42131607-0002-01 | (id:3)
| 42131607-0003-01 | (id:7)
| 42131607-0004-05 | (id:9)
```

Right now I try to using group by but did not able to make correct Query. Help us to make this query

Thanks

Comment: How is `42131607-0001-01` equal to `42131607-0001-02`? I suggest you start by normalizing your database. This will save you a LOT of trouble in the long run.

Comment: `GROUP BY LEFT(key, 13)`?